# How can one destroy terraform configuration in Azure efficiently?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have an Azure terraform configuration. It sets up resource groups, key vaults, passwords, etc ...
When I destroy it terraform does the same in reverse - deleting secrets, access polices, key vaults and the last are resource groups.

But, if the resource groups are to be destroyed anyway, it makes sense just to destroy them first - all the child resources will be deleted automatically. But the azurerm provider does not do it this way.

What am I missing here? And if my understanding is correct, is there a way to implement it (without altering the provider, that is) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform's model, each resource is distinct. Although Terraform can see the dependencies you've defined or implied between them, it doesn't actually understand that e.g. a key vault is a child object of a resource group and so the key vault might be deleted as a side-effect of deleting the resource group.

With that said, unfortunately there is no built-in way in Terraform today to achieve the result you are looking for.

A manual approximation of the idea would be to use `terraform state rm` to tell Terraform to "forget" about each of the objects (that is, they will still exist in Azure but Terraform will have no record of them) that will eventually be destroyed as a side-effect of deleting the resource group anyway, and then running `terraform destroy` *will* only delete the resource group, because Terraform will believe that none of the other objects exist yet anyway. However, that is of course a very manual approach that, without some careful scripting, would likely take longer than just letting the Azure provider work through all of the objects in dependency order.

There is [an exploratory issue in the Terraform repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22094) that covers this use-case (disclaimer: I'm the author of that issue), but the Terraform team isn't actively working on that at the time I write this, because efforts are focused elsewhere. The current set of use-cases captured there doesn't quite capture your idea here of having Terraform recognize when it can skip certain destroy operations, so you might choose to share some details about your use-case on that issue to help inform potential future design efforts.

Comment: How about a different approach: 1. run `terraform state list` and grep all the `azurerm_resource_group` resources 2. run `terraform destroy -target=...` targeting each of the identified resource groups 3. run `terraform destroy` to complete the work.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is built this way, it wouldn't traverse the graph and understand that if the resource group is deleted - anything inside resource group will be deleted as well. which isn't even true in some cases. So I would say it doesn't make sense to do that.

Only real time when this is annoying - when you are testing. for that time you can create a script that would initiate resource group deletion and clear local state, for example

Comment: I am curious about cases when destroying a resource group does not destroy its children. Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: easy, you have resources not in this resource group that depend on resources in this resource group. or you have backups\replicated items in an Azure Recovery Vault, maybe couple of others

Comment: In my case all the environment resources are covered under the resource groups in the same configuration. So, when I destroy it - everything goes. In my particular case being able to destroy the root resource groups would have speed up the process.